# Angular 2, exporting typescript variable to templateUrl path

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass in a global variable as part of the templateUrl string in Angular 2. I know, globals are probably not the best way to do things, but this is the only way I can make it work at the present.

**Component**

```
var myConfig = require('../../../global.template');
console.log('template ' + window['templateid']);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-thank-main',
    templateUrl: '../../views/' + window['templateName'] + '/thank-main/thank main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../views/' + window['templateName'] + '/thank-main/thank-main.component.scss'],
    providers: [MainFormComponent, SharedServices]
})
```

**global.template.ts**

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    window['templateName'] = data.template;
 }
};
xhttp.open("GET", www.example.com/, true);
xhttp.send();
```

My global file makes an api request which returns a template id. I would like to concatenate this with the templateUrl so I can dynamically tell my app which view to render. I just can't figure out how to get around the async issue. My template renders prior to `window['templateName']` being assigned its value.  If I hardcode a string and set it equal to `window['templateName']`everything works fine.

Any suggestions or alternative approaches are welcome. Been banging my head against this one for a while now.

Comment: That is not how Angular works: the templates are compiled when the app starts (in JiT mode), or even at build time (in production, AOT mode). So you can't dynamically set the template URL at runtime, especially after the application has started. You'll have to find another strategy for what you want to achieve (which is unknown to us).

Comment: Yea, i was afraid of that. I am trying to build a static site generator of sorts with Angular 2. I would like to have a `views` folder with many different templates inside it. My Angular app would make a request to a `config.json` on S3 and be told which template to render. In that way I could have many different templates, one angular app, and it would spin up different variations of sites. Maybe I am looking at the wrong tool for the job.